# Exclude field when deriving PartialEq

Tags: rust

Is there an easy way to annotate fields in a struct so that they are ignored when deriving the `PartialEq` trait? For example:

```
#[derive(PartialEq,Eq)]
pub struct UndirectedGraph {
    nodes: HashMap<NodeIdx, UndirectedNode>,
    // mapping of degree to nodes of that degree
    degree_index: Vec<HashSet<NodeIdx>>,
}
```

I want two undirected graphs to be considered equal when they have the same `nodes` field, but the `degree_index` field may differ (the vector may contain extra empty hash-sets at the end).

Obviously I could just implement the trait manually, but automatic derivation would be simpler.

Comment: It can be done with a [crate of mine](https://mcarton.github.io/rust-derivative/cmp.html#ignoring-a-field) but not with standard derive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that currently and I doubt it will be supported.

You could consider making the fields that you want to compare into a sub-struct which is derived, which would make the implementation for the larger struct trivial.

Answer (score 12):

Check out the derivative create ([docs](https://mcarton.github.io/rust-derivative/)). It provides alternate `derive` macros with more power than the standard library versions, including ways to ignore fields for [`Hash`](https://mcarton.github.io/rust-derivative/Hash.html#ignoring-a-field) and [`PartialEq`](https://mcarton.github.io/rust-derivative/cmp.html#ignoring-a-field) traits.

Answer (score 8):

I would also recommend the [`derivative`](https://docs.rs/derivative/latest) crate if you need a more sophisticated form of `#[derive]`.

If you only need something like this once or twice, it may be easier to just implement the required traits manually rather than derive them.  `PartialEq` and `Eq` are [very easy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Eq.html#how-can-i-implement-eq) to implement yourself:

```rust
impl PartialEq for UndirectedGraph {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.nodes == other.nodes
    }
}
impl Eq for UndirectedGraph {}
```